# What does "doing X on the go" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "doing X on the go" mean?

Example:

> Use your phone camera to turn anything into a PDF **on the go**.

---

What I have read so far:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_go lists 2 meanings for "on the go":

1. (idiomatic) Actively traveling; busy; moving often. Example: "*A good suitcase is essential for someone who is **on the go** as much as he is.*".
2. In progress; having started. Example: "*The new initiative is now **on the go***".

None of these two meanings match the "doing X on the go" pattern.

The following dictionaries also don't have any meaning  matching the "doing X on the go" pattern:

- https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+go
- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/on-the-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- John is on the go. [started doing something involving moving from one place to another]
- We did it on the go. [we did it as we were doing other things on some particular day]
- I do my homework on the go. [wherever I happen to be as I move around places]

Turn something into a PDF on the go. [when you are not sitting quietly somewhere. When you are "moving" around, during the day]

Answer (score 0):

Macmillan Dictionary's Open Dictionary has a user-submitted entry that confirms [Lambie's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/205485/3023). From https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/on-the-go ([mirror](http://archive.is/LWbYk)):

> *quickly while doing some other activity*. Example: "
>   The new benches with solar-powered USB charging units allow members of the public to charge their smartphones on the go." [This meaning is based on one submitted to the Open Dictionary by: Boris Marchenko from Russian Federation on 18/06/2017].